# php/simplexml adding elements before and after text

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, children

I'm trying to insert elements into an xml document around some text.  Part of the problem may be that this is not well-formed xml and it needs to be easier to read for a human as plain text.  So what I have is something like this:

```
<record>
  <letter>
    <header>To Alice from Bob</header>
    <body>Hi, how is it going?</body>
  </letter>
</record>
```

I need to end up with this:

```
<record>
  <letter>
    <header>To <to>Alice</to> from <from>Bob</from></header>
    <body>Hi, how is it going?</body>
  </letter>
</record>
```

Something similar should be valid html:

```
<p>To <span>Alice</span> from <span>Bob</span></p>
```

I can set the value of the header to a string, but the `<>` are converted to `&lt` and `&gt`, which is no good.  Right now I'm using `$node->header->addChild('to', 'Alice')` and `$node[0]->header = 'plain text'`.

If I do

```
$node->header->addChild('to', 'Alice'); 
$node->header = 'plain text';
$node->header->addChild('from', 'Bob');
```

Then I get

```
<header>plain text <from>Bob</from></header>
```

The 'to' is wiped out.

Quick and dirty ways are to just let it be

```
<header>plain text <to>Alice</to><from>Bob</from></header>
```

And then just open the file a second time and move the elements around.  Or search and replace the &lt and &gt.  That seems the wrong way though.

Is this possible with simpleXML?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the viewpoint of DOM (and SimpleXML is an abstraction on top of that), you're do not insert elements around text. You replace a text nodes with a mix of text nodes and element nodes. SimpleXML has some problems with mixed child nodes, so you might want to use DOM directly. Here is a commented example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<record>
  <letter>
    <header>To Alice from Bob</header>
    <body>Hi, how is it going?</body>
  </letter>
</record>
XML;

// the words and the tags you would like to create
$words = ['Alice' => 'to', 'Bob' => 'from'];
// a split pattern, you could built this from the array
$pattern = '((Alice|Bob))';

// bootstrap the DOM
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate any text node with content
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//text()[normalize-space() != ""]') as $text) {
  // use the pattern to split the text into an list
  $parts = preg_split($pattern, $text->textContent, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  // if it was split actually
  if (count($parts) > 1) {
    /// iterate the text parts
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
      // if it is a word from the list
      if (isset($words[$part])) {
        // add the new element node
        $wrap = $text->parentNode->insertBefore(
          $document->createElement($words[$part]),
          $text
        );
        // and add the text as a child node to it
        $wrap->appendChild($document->createTextNode($part));
      } else {
        // otherwise add the text as a new text node
        $text->parentNode->insertBefore(
          $document->createTextNode($part),
          $text
        );
      }
    }
    // remove the original text node
    $text->parentNode->removeChild($text);
  }
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
  <letter>
    <header>To <to>Alice</to> from <from>Bob</from></header>
    <body>Hi, how is it going?</body>
  </letter>
</record>
```

Comment: Marking as the right answer because it is doing it the right way.  Much better than treating the files as text files and replacing the &lt; and %gt; with < and >.  I didn't put it in my original question, but this is close to my other workaround, which was to load the file as html and do something like:

    <p>To <span data-to="true" data-from="false">Alice</span> from <span data-to="false" data-from="true">Bob</span>

Having both data-to and data-from may be overkill, but belts and suspenders.  Thanks!